# I'm trying to get some text to line up in my footer. Please help!

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move my "Copyright © 2010 Andraste Ventures LLC. All rights reserved." text to the right a little bit so that it lines up with my "What is Ranking Climber" link.

What do I change in my style sheet?

the css file is located at rankingclimber.com/css/style.css
(the footer part is clearly marked)

this is a screen shot of what's going on and what i would like to happen:

http://www.screencast.com/users/rockstarvisible/folders/Jing/media/dd52c497-3679-498b-96a2-dd8b20bbf82d

here's the code for the footer file: rankingclimber.com/footer.php and the footer is called on the main page: rankingclimber.com

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post relevant parts of the code here, you can't expect people to roam through your whole CSS and find it themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update the css for #copy by this `padding: 0px 25px 20px;`

take a look at the image below
[image]

Comment: Hey Thanks Andrew! Sweet screen shot. What editor are you using?

Comment: glad I could help, I'm using chrome browser's inspect element feature. btw you can click the green check mark to mark this the right answer.. good luck

Answer (score 0):

The bottom list items have a 12px margin applied to the `li` element, and an additional 12px margin applied to the inner `a` element, creating a 24px left offset for the list items. The copyright notice only has a 20px left padding applied to it. The `#copy` rule's padding property should therefore be updated to:

```
padding: 0 20px 20px 24px;
```